# Can I use iPhone headphones with microphone on MacBook Pro?

Tags: headphones

Can I use iPhone headphones with microphone on MacBook Pro?

Comment: Following @CajunLuke answer, can you tell us which MBP you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it only works on Unibody Macs. You can also use the volume and play/pause controls.

Comment: I do have a 2010 model of MacBook Pro 15", it works by default - the buildin microphone is "replaced" with the one from the the headphones. There is not need to change the input device on the software. In fact if you try to change it to line-in it will not work, because you still have the line-in/mic line not used.

Comment: An interesting note: in my (fairly ancient) iBook G4, the headphones with inline controls don't get stereo sound *unless* I hold down the "play" button.